# Parsing Arithmetic chars using a stack

Tags: java

The objective isn't to parse actual integers but rather do a stimulation of A+B*C for example outputting ABC*+

I'm not using generics, but rather a self made class for the Stack. I always end with an error out of bound exception referring to peek() method. I've tried tracing it for quite a bit of time, and can't really get what is going wrong.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stack {

    private char[] arr;
    private int maxsize;
    private int top = -1;

    public Stack(int size) {
        maxsize = size;
        arr = new char[maxsize];
    }

    public void push(char x) {
        arr[++top] = x;

    }

    public char pop() {
        return arr[top--];
    }

    public char peek() {
        return arr[top];
    }

    public int size() {
        return top + 1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size() > 0);
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return top == maxsize - 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = sc.next();
        Stack medo = new Stack(99);
        doParse(text);

    }

    public static void doParse(String text) {

        Stack parse = new Stack(900);
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char ch = text.charAt(i);
            switch (ch) {
                case '-':
                case '+':
                    if (parse.isEmpty()) {
                        parse.push(ch);
                    } else {
                        while (!parse.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.print(parse.pop());
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                case '*':
                case '/':
                    if (parse.isEmpty() || parse.peek() == '+'
                            || parse.peek() == '-') {
                        parse.push(ch);
                    } else {
                        while (!parse.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.print(parse.pop());
                        }
                    }
                    ;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print(ch);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Its is called post fix for a tree please google it ... To get proper help please share your stack trace too and not what you understand from the error.

Comment: Clearly you're accessing the array out-of-bounds.  You should use the debugger to determine the value of `top`, and then figure out how it came to be that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `isEmpty()` method does the opposite of what it should.  this is causing you to peek at an empty stack

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (size() > 0);
}
```

it should be

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (size() <= 0);
}
```